# How do I prevent KDM from starting at boot?

Tags: boot, kdm

I would like to stop `kdm` from starting when my computer boots up. Is there a way to do that? `kdm` is my only graphical login program, I do not use `gdm` or `xdm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Disabling it should be as simple as:

```
sudo mv /etc/init/kdm.conf{,disabled}
```

The same should be the true for `gdm` (which also uses a upstart script in `/etc/init/`).

If you want to fine-tune it, edit `/etc/init/kdm.conf` and change its `start on` declarations. Just comment that entire section out and you'll still be able to run `sudo start kdm` when you want a graphical display.

Comment: @Oli what about if I want to prevent `kdm` and `lightdm`? Will it work ok (I mean log in at system will be ok)?